# Integrating VPN Server Selection into a Web Browser?

Tags: browser, vpn

How difficult would it be to program a barebones web browser that included a built-in VPN server selection feature?

Comment: Any "barebones" web server that a single person can implement in reasonable time would be bare indeed.  Consider writing a plugin for an existing web server to meet your needs.

Comment: @EricJ. I think you mean 'browser', not 'server' ?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Browser.  A bare-bones server is actually much, much easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using .net, you can create a forms application that has a web browser control and using windows scripting host, can monitor and create connections.  I doubt very highly that it is possible from within the confines of a sandboxed browser.

Comment: Browser plugins may also offer the necessary flexibility.

Comment: @EricJ. I think it really is down to the requirement, i.e. the browser method may force you to "pick" a browser (or write many).  Didn't stop Amazon from only writing a plugin for Firefox ONLY and not IE for S3.